# What's the equivalent to JavaScript's DataView in Rust?

Tags: rust

In JavaScript, a `DataView` is used when you need to access a block of memory with:

- differing width types (`uint8`, `uint16`, `uint32`, `float32` etc)
- non-aligned data
- specific endianness

`DataView`s are commonly used for networking code, parsing and creating binary file formats, and for implementing virtual machines. While the first two could make do with only sequential access, virtual machines which use a `DataView` as their RAM need to be able to access it freely (randomly even!)

Is there a corresponding library in Rust? I've seen [bytes](https://crates.io/crates/bytes/) and [byteorder](https://crates.io/crates/byteorder/) but they seem more designed for streaming/sequential access rather than free random access.

Comment: Why should rust have this equivalent ? Describe your problem, here your are just bumping a concept from one language to another language. Rust is strongly type, having a dataView is not needed in general.

Comment: @Stargateur Of course it's not needed in general, but it is helpful in some situations, which I outlined above. My specific use case is for a virtual machine, but that doesn't need to be in the question. I could manually write my own code using a u8 array, but I'd like to know what other people with similar use cases do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a systems language, Rust natively has the ability to interact with raw memory, without requiring a specific wrapper.

Therefore, reading a `u32` out of memory simply requires a sprinkling of `unsafe`:

```
fn read_u32(bytes: &[u8]) -> u32 {
    assert!(bytes.as_ptr() as usize % std::mem::align_of::<u32>() == 0);
    assert!(bytes.len() >= 4);

    unsafe { *(bytes.as_ptr() as *const u32) }
}
```

This raw ability can be used to build better abstractions. Notably, abstractions taking care of alignment and endianness.

---

The `byteorder` crate provides such abstraction: the `LitteEndian` and `BigEndian` types both implement the [`ByteOrder`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.2.7/byteorder/trait.ByteOrder.html) trait.

The above function can be improved to:

```
fn read_u32(bytes: &[u8]) -> u32 { LittleEndian::read_u32(bytes) }
```

which will take care of:

- Performing the conversion.
- Handling unaligned access evenly, instead of panicking.
- With explicit endianness.

---

It only really accounts for primitive types, though, which is where the `bytes` crate steps in.

For example, let's decode a [UDP Header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure):

```
use std::io::Cursor;
use bytes::buf::Buf;

struct UdpHeader {
    src_port: u16,
    dst_port: u16,
    length: u16,
    checksum: u16,
}

fn read_udp_header<T: AsRef<[u8]>>(bytes: &mut Cursor<T>) -> UdpHeader {
    UdpHeader {
        src_port: bytes.read_u16_be(),
        dst_port: bytes.read_u16_be(),
        length: bytes.read_u16_be(),
        checksum: bytes.read_u16_be(),
    }
}
```

Which uses the [`Cursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/struct.Cursor.html) struct from standard library and its implementation of the [`Buf`](https://docs.rs/bytes/0.4.10/bytes/buf/trait.Buf.html) trait from `bytes`.

You can create the cursor around a slice of bytes (`&[u8]`) starting at any point of memory; reading from it advances it, positioning it for the next read, and it will handle alignment, endianness and bounds-checking.

*Note: unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a version returning `Option<u16>`; I'd probably extend it if this was a concern.*

---

Thus I think you've got the right idea with the listed crates, they cover all the requirements you laid out.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's very helpful. So your recommendation would be to use a cursor and seek when random access is needed? I guess as most times you're reading more than a single value from each seek this wouldn't end up as a lot more code than the JS DataView pattern where you explicitly pass in the address each time, maybe even less code.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Actually, I would simply build the `Cursor` on the fly. Starting from a `memory: &[u8]`, I'd jump slice it with `split_at(offset).1` and build a `Cursor` on top: `let mut cursor = Cursor::new(memory.split_at(offset).1);`. This avoids having to keep a `Cursor` around and presumes you already keep the memory around, of course :)